# Shell script invocation error command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1 in Xcode 9

Tags: ios, shell, scripting, xcode9-beta, xcode9

I upgraded from xcode 8.3.2 to xcode 9 and I'm getting a build error

> Shell script invocation error
>   command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1

The project is a simple small app with few screens and I'm not using any custom scripts. It is working fine in xcode 8.3.2

Any idea how to fix this issue in Xcode 9?

Comment: did you any solution to this?

Answer (score -1):

Please check, if you have directory

```
/bin/sh
```

May be your system doesn't have such directory

Comment: This directory exists but I'm still getting the error.

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem as @AkshitRewari. Can you please guide how and where to check for "/bin/sh"?

Comment: You can see the directory at Mac HD directory or by using option go to folder in finder and type /bin  The issue is still unresolved. Rolled back to using xcode 8.3. got no answer for your

Comment: BTW you must enable hidden files in finder to see that directory

Comment: Thanks. I also have this directory exist but issue not resolved. I need to continue with xcode 9 as its required. Please help me if anyone can.